# how to create a robot keyword using python

Tags: python, import, robotframework, keyword

can you help me, please?
I want to create a robot keyword using Python, not the robot framework: meaning not a robot resource file but a Python file. This keyword is going to be used later in a robot test case.

I tried this approach but it did not work and the keyword and the file are unknown
code :

```
    from robot.api import logger
    from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
    from robot.api.deco import not_keyword, library, keyword

    @library
    class MyClass():
       #code
       @keyword  
       def class_method(self):
          #code
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you add a Robot file where you import `MyClass` and try to run a keyword?

Answer (score 0):

Just pay attention that your Python file is named the same as your class!
e.g. here it should be named **MyClass.py** in order RobotFramework could access your Python keywords.

E.g. Working example:

**RobotFramework** test file demo1.robot:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  MyClass.py

*** Test Cases ***
Test 1
    Print Me1    Hello World!
    Print Me2    Hello Space!
    Print Me3    Hello Universe!
```

Python file **MyClass.py**, put it in the same folder as the robot file (or change import path).

```py
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn


class MyClass:

    def print_me1(self, value):
        BuiltIn().log_to_console("object method works: " + value)

    @classmethod
    def print_me2(cls, value):
        BuiltIn().log_to_console("class method works: " + value)

    @staticmethod
    def print_me3(value):
        BuiltIn().log_to_console("static method works: " + value)
```